# Finding union, intersection and difference of two single dimension arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that gives the union, intersection and difference of two arrays that are created by the user's input. Thus, if the user wanted the first array to be of size 4 with the elements [1 2 3 4] and the second array to be of size 5 with the elements [3 4 5 6 7], then the output should come back with; The union of set A and set B is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
                              The intersection of set A and set B is: 3 4
                              The difference of set A and set B is: 1 2
Right now the intersection is obtained but, the difference doesn't work. The difference is printed out as all the elements of the first array. I have no idea where to start with the union. Here is my code:

```
package rhc91310a13sets;

import java.util.*;

public class rhc91310a13sets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] setA = null;
        int[] setB = null;

        System.out.print("Enter size for set A (must be less than or equal to 20): ");
        setA = new int[sc.nextInt()];

        System.out.print("Enter elements for set A between 1-20: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
            setA[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print('\n');

        System.out.print("Enter size for set B (must be less than or equal to 20): ");
        setB = new int[sc.nextInt()];

        System.out.print("Enter elements for set B between 1-20: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < setB.length; i++) {
            setB[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print('\n');

        System.out.print("The union of sets A and B are: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < setB.length; j++) {
                }
            }       

        System.out.print('\n');

        System.out.print("The intersection of sets A and B are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < setB.length; j++) {
                if (setA[i] == setB[j]) {
                    System.out.print(setA[i] + " ");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print('\n');

        System.out.print("The difference of sets A and B are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < setB.length; j++) {
                if (!(setA[i] == setB[j])) 
                    System.out.print(setA[i] + " ");        
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a HashSet? Then all these operations are just a method call.

Comment: Problem is, say `setA[0] == setB[1]`, `setA[0] == setB[0]` is probably false, which means it will be printed. You have to check every element, only then if there is no collision: print it.

Comment: This smells of homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your unexpected result

```
The difference of sets A and B are: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

your logic has some problems.you check difference between `setA` and `set B` by taking one element from setA and check is it different from setB's element,but the problem.for example you take `1` from setA and check is it different from `3 ,4, 5, 6 ,7` .so it's different from all 5 elements,so 1 will print 5 times.the worst problem happen when you take 3 from setA and check with the setB.3 is different from all elements expect 1st element in setB.so `3` will print `4 times` .but wait this gives the idea .if a element of setA print `less than 5 times` that mean it's not different element. what you have to do is check is it different all 5 elements not with single ,i put count variable and check is it 5 times different from setB.but i think simple way is use `HashSet`

```
int[] setA = {1,2,3,4};
int[] setB = {3 ,4, 5, 6 ,7};
int count=0;
System.out.print("The difference of sets A and B are: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
    count=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < setB.length ; j++) {
        if ((setA[i] != setB[j])){ 
            count++;

        } 
        if(count==setB.length){
            System.out.println(setA[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

output>>

```
The difference of sets A and B are: 
1
2
```

*****update*****

if you wanna put different elements of this 2 in a array best way is arraylist .you can do like following

```
int[] setA = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] setB = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int count = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();

System.out.print("The difference of sets A and B are: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < setB.length; j++) {
        if ((setA[i] != setB[j])) {
            count++;

        }
        if (count == setB.length) {
           // System.out.println(setA[i]);
            arl.add(i);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(arl);
```

output>>

```
The difference of sets A and B are: 
1
2
[0, 1]
```

finding union values.you can use HashSet.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<setA.length;i++){
    list.add(setA[i]);
}
for(int i=0;i<setB.length;i++){
    list.add(setB[i]);
}
HashSet h = new HashSet();
h.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list .addAll(h);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I suspect that for union I will need to create a third array.

Comment: do you wanna get different elements  to a array?

Comment: The idea is to print out all the elements from the first array and the second array without printing out any duplicates. Would something along the lines of int[] setC = new int[setA.length + setB.length] get me close or am I way off base here? Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hermes "without printing out any duplicates" so this will not give duplicates.don't you wanna get 1 and 2 only?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about finding the union of the two arrays. Your suggestions for finding the difference were spot on.

Comment: @Hermes so what is your expected result ?

Comment: If the user wanted the first array to be of size 4 with the elements [1 2 3 4] and the second array to be of size 5 with the elements [3 4 5 6 7], then the output should come back with; The union of set A and set B is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7